# I need a solution to setting up a sign-up button, check Line 7, the signupactivity shows red on Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

class Main3Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    btn5_sign_up.setOnClickListener() {
        LoginActivity(Intent(this.SignUpActivity::class.java))
        finish()

    }
}

public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    var currentUser = auth.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}
//assigning the function previously named above
fun updateUI (currentUser : FirebaseAuth?){


}
```

[Basically, line 7 is not making the code go through with the red on SignUpActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsANb.png)

Comment: Use this@SignUpActivity instead of this.SignUpActivity::class.java, Here want to access outer class inside click listener, kotlin does not allow like you written

Comment: Dharmesh, I do not understand your comment except you mean I should use "@SignUpActivity" instead of ",SignUpActivity" and this is still indicating red for the "SignUpActivity"

Comment: Use "this@SignUpActivity" not only @SignUpActivity

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
startActivity(Intent(this,SignUpActivity::class.java))
```

Instead of
`LoginActivity(Intent(this.SignUpActivity::class.java))`

Comment: I have corrected as suggested but I still have the red for the SignUpActivity

Comment: Ooh, great!! If my answer helped you, please upvote it. Thanks